# disable/enable button when checkboxes is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a MVC application in C# and in a view that will have  some checkboxes and on this list of checkboxes some checkboxes will come  "checked and disable" from the database depends if I pass some or other value of ID.
But my problem is my button only can submit if i check a checkbox enable or if i have more than 2 enable and checked all the checkboxes enabled and not checked the checkbox disabled. 
[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/senoritave83/f4hxufqx/4/)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" id="checkboxPrincipal" />SelectALL


    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {


<input type="checkbox"   id="mycheckbox" class="mycheck"  onchange="isChecked(this,'myButton');" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="checkbox"   id="mycheckbox" class="mycheck" onchange="isChecked(this,'myButton');"/>
<input type="checkbox"   id="mycheckbox" class="mycheck" onchange="isChecked(this,'myButton');"/>


                }




    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="myButton" name="myButton" disabled >Actualizar</button>


        <script type="text/javascript">
         function isChecked(mycheckbox,myButton) {
            console.log(myButton);
            var myLayer = document.getElementById(myButton);
            if (mycheckbox.checked == true) {
                myLayer.disabled = false;
            } else {
                myLayer.disabled = true;
            }
        }


        $('.checkboxPrincipal').change(function () {
           if ($('.checkboxPrincipal:checked').length == $('.checkboxPrincipal').length) {
              $('#myButton').prop('disabled',true);
           }
           else{
              $('#myButton').prop('disabled',false);
           }
         });

    </script>
```

Comment: it is not very clear what's the question. something like how do I enable submit button when...when what? could you please describe that condition?

Comment: looking at the checkboxes -- elements should have unique id, otherwise is bug-prone

Comment: could you please edit your question. no idea what you mean by `check a checkbox enable or if i have more than 2 enable and checked all the checkboxes enabled and not checked the checkbox disabled`

Comment: when you open the fiddle, you expect enabled checkboxes to be checked?

Comment: Yes, but not the disabled and checked checkboxes . Its works when i check ony by one and the button is enable. but when i SelectAll i dont know whats happen.     https://jsfiddle.net/senoritave83/hcsjz1do/1/

Answer (score -1):

you can use checked attribute of checkbox and disabled attribute of button in jQuery like this example :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if(chkbox1.checked==true) {
   $('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

});

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/senoritave83/hcsjz1do/4/  Thanks TheSelectall works !!!!!!! But my problem now is when I check / uncheck one by one I lose the action of enabled /disable button.